# Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying sample report. I connected database successfully.

I wrote simple query

```sql
select country, population from dataset
```

```sql
desc dataset;


| country    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| population | int(9)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I have taken blank chart , In this I used XY Line chart. X-axis i have given *country* and y-axis *population*. When I click preview button, i am getting below error.

```
Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillXySeries.evaluate(JRFillXySeries.java:159)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillXyDataset.customEvaluate(JRFillXyDataset.java:121)    
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementDataset.evaluate(JRFillElementDataset.java:155)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.calculateVariables(JRCalculator.java:160)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:765)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a standard line chart not a XY line chart.

XY line charts need the categories (in your case Country) and a (X,Y) point.

Answer (score 0):

For Line chart, in Chart Data, Category Expression (Y axis) should be value that could be cast to Number, and Value Expression (X axis) could be string.  If these 2 values are not mixed up, we will have the cast to Number error.